# What do we call an 'attempt' at a rebuttal?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the most effective word that describes an 'attempt' at rebutting a given argument? Emphasis on 'Attempt.' I hope find to a word which implies that:

**the attempt is *not* a successful one** (that's why I don't use just 'rebuttal') **and could easily been repudiated depute its seeming irrefutable.**

As in

This _______ [?] may be addressed by calling the audience's attention to the fact that . . .

Something like that.

Thank you

Comment: Just use *rebuttal* and, in conversation, use air quotes and dripping sarcasm.  In written form, use scare quotes and if you feel it's necessary prepend "*so called*"

Comment: You may "challenge the argument". for example, "*I call the audience attention on an interesting way to challenge the argument*".

Answer (score 2):

**Rebuttal** does not necessarily mean **refute**: that is, a *rebuttal* is not necessarily a successful refutation of an argument.  However, it sometimes carries that connotation (see [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rebuts)).  Synonyms of *rebuttal* that normally do not connote success include **retort**, **counterargument**, and **rejoinder**.

[*Retort*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retort) is usually a quick response:

> 1 :  to answer back usually sharply
>   2 :  to return an argument or charge (MW)

[*Counterargument*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/counterargument) is simply an opposing argument:

> An argument in opposition to another. (TFD)

And [*rejoinder*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rejoinder) can simply mean a *reply*, though it technically means a reply to a reply:

> a reply or response to a question or remark, esp a quick witty one; retort
>   an answer to a reply; response. (TFD)